# Excel - Create a countdown that ignores blanks; Take the minimum date of 3 columns - TODAY(),

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to create a column that displays the number of days between now and the next time a person is required to participate in a study.

If there were no blanks in the columns that list the dates, the following formula works (N,P & R contain dates):

```
=MIN(N5,P5,R5)-TODAY()
```

Unfortunately, my data contains blanks in the columns, which returns a "N/A" value.

Does anyone know how to avoid counting blanks in this situation?
Please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Just going through your history, when you get a correct answer one should click the check mark by the answer that was used.  You should go back through your questions and mark those answers correct.  People stop helping those who do not give proper feedback.

Comment: Thanks, Scott. being new to the community,  I hadn't seen the check mark previously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SMALL` function will ignore any blanks, so you can use this formula

`=SMALL((N5,P5,R5),1)-TODAY()`

If all three cells are blank you'll get a `#NUM!` error so you might want to add an `IFERROR` function to handle that, e.g.

`=IFERROR(SMALL((N5,P5,R5),1)-TODAY(),"")`

Comment: This is working beautifully. Thanks for adding the IFERROR.

Answer (score 1):

use this array formula:

```
=MIN(IF(CHOOSE({1,2,3},N5,P5,R5)>0,CHOOSE({1,2,3},N5,P5,R5))) - TODAY()
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

Comment: This is a great array formula. It works great, as long as at least one of the date columns contains a value; however I am getting a negative figure if all three date columns are blank. I should have clarified that this could potentially be the case.

Comment: as Barry did, wrap the whole in an IFERROR and return a blank.  But Barry's answer is better.